# RTK Query Interceptor Circular Dependency

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Trying to figure out the best way to achieve the following:

1. API via `createApi`
2. Auth slice via `createSlice`
3. Clear the redux auth state when the API receives a 401.

No problem with the first 2! But the issue is when I need to add an interceptor to the API (invalid auth - clear the local auth state):

```ts
// api.ts
import authSlice from './authSlice';
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError> = async (
  args,
  api,
  extraOptions
) => {
  const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

  if (result.error?.status === 401) {
    api.dispatch(authSlice.actions.clearAuth())
  }

  return result
}

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: API_REDUCER_KEY,
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
})
```

```ts
// authService.ts
import { User } from '../../models/User'
import { api } from '../api'

export const API_REDUCER_KEY = 'api'

interface AuthResponse {
  user: User
  jwt: string
}

interface LoginData {
  email: string
  password: string
}

export const authApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation<AuthResponse, LoginData>({
      query: (body) => {
        return {
          url: 'login',
          method: 'POST',
          body,
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useLoginMutation } = authApi
```

This causes a circular dependency - as the auth slice needs to call the API for the auth functions (login, logout, etc.):

```ts
// authSlice.ts
import { api } from './api';
...
export const loginLocal = createAsyncThunk<
  Pick<AuthState, 'user' | 'accessToken'>,
  {
    email: string
    password: string
  }
>('auth/login', async ({ email, password }, { dispatch }) => {
  const response = await dispatch(
    authApi.endpoints.login.initiate({
      email,
      password,
    })
  )

  if ('error' in response) {
    if ('status' in response.error) {
      throw new Error(response.error.data as string)
    }
    throw new Error(response.error.message)
  }

  const { data } = response

  const { jwt: accessToken, user } = data

  return { user, accessToken }
})
```

The circular dependency is as follows: authSlice -> authService -> api -> authSlice

Is there a way around this - or is there a better/different pattern I can use?

Comment: wouldn't it solve the problem if you move `baseQueryWithReauth` to a separate file? than you don't have to import `authSlice` in your `api.ts`

Comment: Also, why is `loginLocal` written as a `createAsyncThunk`? That feels like something that would go into the API slice as well.

Comment: @TheWuif - I believe that would still be a circular dependency, just with an extra link in the chain:

authSlice -> authService -> api -> baseQueryWithReauth -> authSlice

Comment: @markerikson - I am applying some async logic in that function as well that isn't relevant to the question :)

Answer (score 5):

An easy solution was to simply pull the "clearAuth" action into it's own file - as per https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices:

> This will usually require extracting shared code to a separate common file that both modules can import and use. In this case, you might define some common action types in a separate file using createAction, import those action creators into each slice file, and handle them using the extraReducers argument.

```ts
// clearAuthAction.ts
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const CLEAR_AUTH = 'auth/clearAuth'

export const clearAuth = createAction<void>(CLEAR_AUTH)
```

Then use the builder in authSlice:

```ts
// authSlice.ts
builder.addCase(CLEAR_AUTH, (state) => {
  state.user = null
  state.accessToken = null
})
```

And dispatch clearAuth in the API:

```ts
// api.ts
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError> = async (
  args,
  api,
  extraOptions
) => {
  const result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)

  if (result.error?.status === 401 || result.error?.status === 403) {
    api.dispatch(clearAuth())
  }

  return result
}
```